# pandas, fillna on multiindex columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
index_tuples=[]

for distance in ["near", "far"]:
    for vehicle in ["bike", "car"]:
        index_tuples.append([distance, vehicle])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tuples, names=["distance", "vehicle"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["city"], columns = index)



d = {(x,y):my_home_city[x][y] for x in my_home_city for y in my_home_city[x]}
df.loc['my_home_city',:]=d
df
Out[994]: 
distance     near       far     
vehicle      bike  car bike  car
city          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
my_home_city    1    0    0    1
```

I'd like to do `df['near']['bike'].fillna(False, inplace=True)`

it says

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529), so assign back selected column by `tuple`:

```
df[('near', 'bike')] = df[('near', 'bike')].fillna(False)
print (df)
distance       near       far     
vehicle        bike  car bike  car
city          False  NaN  NaN  NaN
my_home_city      1  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

But your solution should be changed:

```
df[('near', 'bike')].fillna(False, inplace=True)
```